# Why can I see a beam of light coming in through the window sometimes, but not all the time?

Tags: visible-light, scattering, vision

Does it have to do with moisture in the air?  Does it have to do with the window itself?  Could the light reflect/refract off of the air?  If there were no moisture or smoke or dust, just air, would I see the beam of light? What part does contrast of the light compared to the rest of the room have to do with visibility of the light in "mid-air?"  IT looks like this

http://mayazest.blogspot.com/2013/07/how-to-make-volumetric-lights-and-fog.html

Comment: Google for "god ray" images. One can see sunlight in the air... there is always enough scattering to see it, if the contrast is high enough.

Comment: I know you can see beams of light outside sometimes too... Why though? Why do I see specific beams of light? Would I see those beams if there were nothing in the air, no moisture, dust, etc.?

Comment: The blue sky is nothing but scattered sunlight, you just don't see individual rays because there is not aperture to create a contrast between light and dark areas. With the right cloud formations nature makes that aperture for you for scattering in the lower atmosphere.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it really doesn't answer my question.

Comment: Maybe someone can draw it out for you, it's really just a geometry problem.

Comment: I tried to simplify/clarify the question

Comment: There you go... an image from space: http://blogs.discovermagazine.com/badastronomy/2011/11/02/crepuscular-rays-are-parallel/#.Vt-_GoyIbu0. Scattering of sunlight made visible against the surface.

Comment: Do you mean beams of light alternating at same instant of time?

Answer (score 1):

You generally need 2 things:

- scatterers (there are always some)
- especially for low amount of scatterers, have your gaze direction close to the light incidence, because it maximize the number of illuminated scatterers in a row in your point of view. This is why you see god rays through clouds or at mountain silhouettes in the sky.

This is also the reason why you see a laser beam, and why you see it better when it point closer to your direction. (In a true Stars War, you won't see laser in the vacuum, at least before the first explosion of some starship).

Comment: You wouldn't see the laser move either for that matter, meaning ships would seem to emit bright light then explode.  Considering that there would be no noise, a real star wars battle would be a little confusing.

Comment: I meant that if the laser is still on in the dust of debris, you'll see the beam via illuminated dust.